# CURL POST Request to Bot Framework

Tags: curl, botframework

I created a Bot using Microsoft Bot Framework and I am able to connect to it through Emulator and Web Chat. I have user login in my UI and once the user is logged in , i need to send the username and some other details to Bot end point. So that Bot can directly greet the user from the information which i posted and get in to chat. I created CURL post requests , but its not hitting that end point. Any one , please point me on the issue here. A sample of CURL POST request would be great help.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make the chat by post requests... Here is the method.

1. **Get the conversationId by making a post call.**

   1. Setup the Directline chat and copy the Direct Line Secret.
   2. Make post call as follows

      `curl -X POST --header 'Accept: application/json 'https://directline.botframework.com/api/conversations/'`

      with this header

      `Authorization: BotConnector "Your Direct Line Secret Here"`

      The response is a json with a conversationId field. You'll need it for any conversation you'll make from here on
2. **Send Messages using a post call**

   1. Send a post call with the same Header with an extra field for the `Content-Type: application/json`

      `curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"text": "Hi"}' 'https://directline.botframework.com/api/conversations/1234/messages'`
   2. The body will contain the json as mentioned in the api reference

Look at this [Direct Line API Reference](http://docs.botframework.com/sdkreference/restapi-directline/) for more information. Remember to regenerate the access token as it would expire in 30 minutes. I would still prefer the connector client method. Its easier to keep the context and there's no need to regenerate tokens.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers. I am using Web Chat and i am not going to use Microsoft Web Chat IFRAME. Because you dont have proper control over there. What i am looking is directly connecting the Bot Backend with out having this https://directline.botframework.com or https://webchat.botframework.com. MS Emulator is able to hit the Bot Rest End point directly. I am tryng to replicate the same thing in a custom web UI

Comment: Good answer for Direct Line 1.1. See my answer for Direct Line 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible. You can *talk* with the bot only through the **connector client** out of the emulator, sending a POST request won't work unless you set up the Direct Line API, which in turn invokes the connector client. You can use the connector client to set the user details into the bot user data and use it else where. Here is a sample C# code to do it.

```
var client = new ConnectorClient(appId, appSecret);
var getData = await client.Bots.GetUserDataAsync(appId, userid);
getData.Data = "Your User Details in some form as a string (I'd prefer a serialized JSON)";
await client.Bots.SetUserDataAsync(Constants.botId, userid, getData);
```

Once set you can always access it using `message.botuserdata`. Note: userid can be accessed as `message.From.Id`

Answer (score 0):

I have a bot deployed on an internal web server and I have a client application (not a web client) talking to it using REST API calls quite happily.

I don't know if the same concept will work if you use the Azure URL for the bot (as opposed to the URL in the Bot Framework) but it might be worth a go. If the Bot Emulator can talk to Azure, then any REST API should work.

You'll need to a suitable JSON string to send as the body of the message. I copied the JSON you see in the Bot Emulator and used that as a basis.

```
    Dim client As RestClient = New RestClient(_localAddress) 'Address of the Bot
    Dim request As RestRequest = New RestRequest("api/messages", Method.POST)

    Dim byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_appID & ":" & _appsecret) ' Appropriate application secret and ID
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic " & Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray))
    'messageDetails is my message class dervived from the Json from the Bot Emulator
    messageDetails.text = messageToRelay

    request.AddJsonBody(messageDetails)
    ' response is then deserialised to a suitable BotReply class, again based on the Json you can see in Bot Emulator 
    Dim response = client.Execute(request)
```

You'll need to manage some of the variables in the relevant classes to maintain the chain of messages, but by examining the Json responses you can see in the Bot Emulator you should be able to pick it out

I appreciate that the answer isn't CURL based, but hopefully it might help and you can adapt as needed

Answer (score 0):

[Direct Line 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-start-conversation?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)

Get site token from Azure portal (Bot -> channels -> Direct Line -> Default_Site -> Secret keys). Replies can be taken from either a websocket, or from polling.

```
# replace with site token from channels > directline > site > secret_keys
site_token="x*****************************************************0"

# create conversation
json=$(curl -s -X POST \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ${site_token}" \
  https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations)

# conversation ID
# (apt-get install jq if required)
cid=$(echo "${json}" | jq .conversationId | sed 's/"//g')
echo "cid=${cid}"
# websocket URL for reply stream
url=$(echo "${json}" | jq .streamUrl | sed 's/"//g')
# there are also fields:
#   token - a time limited access token
#   expires_in - the expiry in seconds
#   referenceGrammarId

# post text to bot
json=$(curl -s -X POST \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ${site_token}" \
  -d '{
    "locale": "en-EN",
    "type": "message",
    "from": {
        "id": "user1"
    },
    "text": "hello"
  }' \
  https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/${cid}/activities)

# post reply has an activity ID, could be useful
activity_id=$(echo "${json}" | jq .id | sed 's/"//g')

# connect to websocket and listen for reply
nvm use node
# nvm install -g wscat if you haven't installed it yet
wscat -c "${url}"

# OR poll for replies (less efficient)
curl -i -X GET \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ${site_token}" \
  https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/${cid}/activities
```

[Direct Line 1.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-1-1-send-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)

This older version still works, but requires polling for replies (no websocket).

```
# replace with site token from channels > directline > site > secret_keys
site_token="x*****************************************************0"

# create conversation
json=$(curl -s -X POST \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ${site_token}" \
  https://directline.botframework.com/api/conversations)
cid=$(echo "${json}" | jq .conversationId | sed 's/"//g')

# post text to bot
curl -s -X POST \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ${site_token}" \
  -d '{
  "text": "hello",
  "from": "user1"
}' \
  https://directline.botframework.com/api/conversations/${cid}/messages

# get replies
curl -i -X GET \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ${site_token}" \
  https://directline.botframework.com/api/conversations/${cid}/messages
```